# Exact sequence, direct sum, understanding of the given proof

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-explanation, direct-sum

> Let $0\to A\to E\to B\to 0$ be an exact sequence of commutativ groups with $A$ and $B$ finite with orders $a$ and $b$, where $\gcd(a,b)=1$.
>   $B'=\{x\in E|bx=0\}$.
>
> Then is $E=A\oplus B'$ and $B'$ is the only subgroup of $E$ isomorphic to $B$.

Proof:

Since $\gcd(a,b)=1$ there are $r,s\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $ar+bs=1$.
If $x\in A\cap B'$, then $ax=bx=0$, hence $(ar+bs)x=x=0$; and $A\cap B'=0$. Moreover, all $x\in E$ can be written as $x=arx+bsx$; since $bB'=0$, we have $bE\subset A$, hence $bsx\in A$; on the other hand, from $abE=0$ follows that $arx\in B'$. Hence we see that $E=A\oplus B'$ and the projection $E\to B$ defines an isomorphism of $B'$ onto $B$. Conversly, if $B''$ is a subgroup of $E$ isomorphic to $B$, we have $bB''=0$ hence $B''\subset B'$ and $B''=B'$ because these groups have the same order.

I have some questions to steps of this proof. Some are clear, but others I simply do not get.

1.) Why does from $x\in A\cap B'$ follows, that $ax=bx=0$. That $bx=0$ is clear. But why is $ax=0$.
I tried using, that the given sequence is exact and I believe that all the steps which I do not get use this fact. 
But I simply do not see how and where my mistake is.

2.) Why does from $bB'=0$ follow, that $bE\subset A$ and the elements in $A$ are from the form $bsx$?

3.) Why is $abE=0$ and similar to 2.) why is $arx\in B'$.

4.) What is meant with the projection $E\to B$?

I would appreciate a hint on which part of the properties I do not understand, so I can think about the exact arguments myself.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by the question you give,the group means additiveq group.
1.since the order of A is n,so nx=0;

2.denote $p:E\rightarrow B$,$p(by)=bp(y)=0,\forall y\in E$,since the order of B is $b$,so $by\in A$.
$bE'=0$ I think is superflous.

3.$abE=0$ since $bE\subset A$.

4.remark you can understand $B\cong E/A$,so the projection means $E\rightarrow E/A$

Comment: Is there a point in the proof, where we need that the groups are commutativ? I think it is needed for $(ar+bs)x=x=0$. Am I right? Why does your function $p: E\to B$, $p(by)=bp(y)=0$ work? If it works I understand why, but I do not see, why it works to observe this function.

Comment: Why can we understand $B\cong E/A$? Is this because we have an exact sequence?

Comment: @Cornman additive group is commutative.Remark p is homomorphism of additive group.In particular,p is $\mathbb Z$-module homomorphism.

Comment: Every group denoted additiv is commutativ? I think I see it now for $p$. $p$ maps every element of $E$ into $B$ and therefore we have that $bp(y)=0$. So we just needed to find such a mapping to conclude, that $bE\subseteq A$?

Comment: @Cornman Remark A is Kernel